# iOS - How to display emoji in UILabel from unicode character

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, decimal

I need to display an emoji in a `UILabel` from Unicode decimal.

I have the following value `128513`
[image]
(from Unicode table: http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect/hex/1F601)

Is it possible? I got it using a hexadecimal Unicode, but now I need to show emoji from decimal Unicode, because of an API that I'm using.

Comment: I know how to convert the Hex value to Emoji in a UILabel. Let me know if you have an alternative.

Answer (score -2):

```
[yourString stringbyreplacingpercentescapesusingencoding NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

While showing to label.

Comment: I can't to find the in the documentation how to use the method you said, can you explain?

Comment: stringbyreplacingpercentescapesusingencoding

Comment: stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding is deprecated in iOS 9.0

Comment: Yes but it is one option, there are other way arounds for ios 9.

Comment: @ArpitBParekh If it's working for you, please provide the code using one Unicode example.